# Category of Sets w/ 17 Elements: There does not exist a direct product? (Lots of questions here)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, category-theory

I'm having a pretty hard time with this. I'm asked to show that, in the category of *sets with exactly 17 elements*, no two objects have either a direct product nor direct sum. Part of me doesn't even believe this statement—but whenever I try to come up with a direct product, I get snagged.

Let $(C, \alpha, \beta)$ be a [potential] direct product of $A$ and $B$. Fix some object, $C'$, with mappings, $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$, from $C'$ to $A$ and $B$ respectively. We need a unique $\gamma: C' \rightarrow C$ such that $\alpha \circ \gamma = \alpha'$ and $\beta \circ \gamma = \beta'$.

- $C = A \times B$ just can't work, because $A \times B$ necessarily has more than 17 elements (in fact, **no** Cartesian-product-like $C$ can work, because the number of elements is fixed). What about some 17-element subset of $A \times B$? (In the category of sets, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are injective, but not necessarily surjective). But, what if $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ are both surjective? So, that can't work, because there's no $\gamma$ that could satisfy this (doesn't that mean that, in the general category of sets, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to *also* be surjective? If they don't "touch" every element in both $A$ and $B$, then one can just define a $\alpha'$ or $\beta'$ that touches the elements $\alpha$ or $\beta$ don't—thus making impossible a direct product.)
- Let $\alpha(c_n) = a_n$ and $\beta(c_n) = b_n$. This contains bijective $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but all we have to do is define a $C'$ such that $\alpha'(c_1) = a_1$ and $\beta'(c_1) = b_2$.

Ok. So, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have to be bijective. Let's try to prove this via negation: Since these mappings are necessarily bijective, they have to have an inverse. Thus, $\gamma$ must be such that $\gamma = \alpha^{-1} \circ \alpha'$ **and** $\gamma = \beta^{-1} \circ \beta'$. To show that we can choose an object $C'$ where $\gamma$ *can't* make the graph commute, just choose $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ such that $\alpha^{-1} \circ \alpha \neq \beta^{-1} \circ \beta$.

1. Can I assume that such an $\alpha'$ and $\beta'$ will always exist?
2. Was there no point to the number of elements being $17$ specifically? This all seems to work for **any** category of sets with a fixed number of elements.
3. Is there something crucial I'm missing?

Comment: What are the morphisms of your category?

Comment: Just set-mappings; the same as the morphisms in the more general category of sets.

Comment: The product projections in $\mathsf{Set}$ don't have to be epic. Consider $\emptyset \times X \to X$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, I don't know a couple of the terms you used here. I am assuming "product projections" is the same thing as "product," and that "epic" is the same thing as "bijective." Please correct me if I'm mistaken! That being said: If the product is $\emptyset \times X$, then if $\alpha: \emptyset \times X \rightarrow X$, doesn't $\alpha$ have to be bijective? We know it's injective, an in order for a direct product to exist, it also has to touch every element in $X$ or else another object could via some map (sorry, having a bit of a hard time w/o drawing a graph, haha).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I guess I don't understand why $\emptyset \times X \rightarrow X$ is a remarkable example. Wouldn't that just be the product of $\emptyset$ and $X$, where $\alpha: \emptyset \times X \rightarrow X$ such that $\alpha((\emptyset, x \in X)) = x$ and $\beta: \emptyset \times X \rightarrow \emptyset$ such that $\beta((\emptyset, X)) = \emptyset$ ? ... ooooooh, since there are no elements in $\emptyset$, $\beta$ can't possibly be surjective... ... or... or it's **always** surjective. Do we just define it as *not* being surjective?

Comment: Notice $\emptyset \times X = \emptyset$. The unique map $\emptyset \to X$ is surjective if and only if $X=\emptyset$. This follows from the definitions of "surjective", "map", "empty set". It is not a convention.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Oh! I did not think of $\emptyset \times X$ as being equal to $\emptyset$. Since $A \times B$ is an ordered pair, $(a, b)$, I thought $\emptyset \times X$ would be something like $(  ,x)$, hah. What you said makes sense.

Comment: In set theory, $A \times B$ is a set of ordered pairs. It itsself is not an ordered pair. If $A$ is empty, or $B$ is empty, then $A \times B$ is empty, too.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah! Right, right. I am getting sets and the more general categories mixed up here!

Thanks. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $n \geq 2$. If $A,B$ have a product $P$ in the category of sets with $n$ elements, then $\hom(A,P) \cong \hom(A,A) \times \hom(A,B)$ shows $n^n = n^n \cdot n^n$, a contradiction.

Comment: But this is assuming that the product in the category of sets is the same as the product in the category of sets *with exactly 17 elements*. Why can I make that assumption?

Comment: No, I don't assume this. Recall that $X \times Y$, in any category, is defined by $\hom(-,X \times Y) \cong \hom(-,X) \times \hom(-,Y)$.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this. Quickly looking up some notation, you're using hom functors, yes? (I haven't seen these yet—the exercise I was working on was in the first chapter of *Mathematical Physics* by Geroch; $X \times Y$ has been defined only in terms of the Cartesian Product between sets.)

Comment: You don't have to know about hom-functors. If $(X \leftarrow P \rightarrow Y)$ is a product, you can directly verify that there is a bijection $\hom(T,P) \cong \hom(T,X) \times \hom(T,Y)$ for all objects $T$. (Actually this is natural in $T$, but this is irrelevant for the exercise.)

Comment: Oh. $hom(T,P)$ just refers to the "set" of morphisms from $T$ to $P$?

What is $hom(T, X) \times hom(T, Y)$ defined categorically? (I know it's something like the Cartesian Product set-wise, but do all categories have an equivalent?)

Comment: 1) Yes, this is the set of morphisms. 2) This is just the usual cartesian product of sets.

Comment: So everything **is** formulated in sets (my quotation-marks around the word "set" were unnecessary)! That makes things easier. I thought that, since we're speaking of general categories, we'd want to avoid specific set-category—but this is like... meta-sets of categories (which include sets), isn't it? Isn't there a bunch of weird recursion going on there? (Anyway, thanks so much for your help!)

Comment: In some sense this is recursive, because we have to know the category of sets $\mathsf{Set}$ in order to make sense of the notion of a locally small category, which is, in fact, a $\mathsf{Set}$-enriched category. But this is not the case for the more general notion of a category. Here, a product $(X \leftarrow P \rightarrow Y)$ is described by a first-order property: For every span $(X \leftarrow T \rightarrow Y)$ there should be a unique morphism $T \to P$ such that the two triangles commute. This even makes sense if $\hom(T,P)$ is not a set. But in our case it is, anyway.